# Need some Help for game Development in Android

Tags: android, touch, render, surfaceview

We are currently developing a RPG with Android using a Renderer and Canvas.

Our "Main" method is a Surfaceview where we call different stuff like the Map, Monsters and at least the Character. All of them are Drawable and have a thread where they can change their pixel Position if they need to move to the next Block at the MapArray. This means our Map is devided in Squares and if they move they got a thread with a sleep which changes its Pixel Position. If the render draws them, it get draw at the pixel position not at the MapArray position. (The render is in ouar surfaceview the renderloop got its own class)
The render draws first the Map (background scaled to the Viewsize), char + skill if used, monsters and at least the Interface.

At the Moment the surfaceview doesn't have a XML layout and i am bit confused if we need it one? At the moment it's the surface is called from the Mainactivity by a Startbutton

The next question is, how to i realize the touchevents. Do i really need to get the event in the surfaceview check if its at the right square and call the function by squere? 
or is there a way to draw a the joypad (Bitmap maybe lateron a Sprite) and make it touchable or something like that?
Does it automatically support multitouch? (Moving and using a skill at the same time)

Is there something we just did really wrong in the basic idear and implementation? (if you need some Code let me know)

Best Regards
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't see the point of having an XML layout if you only have one single `SurfaceView` on screen and if your game rendering is done in it.
2. For the touch events I don't see any other option than handling touch events of the SurfaceView (by overriding `onTouchEvent()` method) and check the coordinates to decide what to do with it.

Comment: Okay than we already made it right. How about if we want to open a Menü? Do we simply use a XML layout for that?

How does the Surfaceview works correctly? If we close the app it actually crashes. We just simply stop all threads like monster movement and Render.

Comment: I guess so, though I'd personally rather go for a high-level game framework that handles sprites and so on instead of building from scratch with a SurfaceView

Comment: Well at this point of Implemnation we just use static Bitmap. Lateron i would like to replace it with Sprites. The rest of the animation thread (which simply move the bitmap at the moment) will be the same. it just changes the sprite too lateron.

Comment: Search about LibGDX or Andengine. They both handle a big part of OpenGL stuff, you just draw the images on the screen and release resources when the app is closed. Not that hard.

Comment: As @miNde says, using a game framework like Andengine could help you save an awful lot of time by not reinventing the wheel :). but doing from scratch is a nice way to learn too

Comment: Well we are doing it as Project for the university and allready made alot of work with it. All movement and so on are already working correctly. We just dont got animation yet but this shouldnt be a problem. So i dont care if we should rewrite all that stuff again with Andengine for example. I guess we are on the right way even if we could make it more easy. We are not sure if we even need to animate lateron for our projekt ;)

Comment: @Benjamin If the game was well designed (MVC pattern) it will not be a problem to adapt it for LibGDX, as LibGDX is not dedicated to a platform, unlike Andengine which has been designed for Android only. And LibGDX also have a Sprite class.

Comment: I am not sure if we done the MVC pattern correct but i guess so. With LibGDX we would simply change the render a bit (no canvas anymore), the draw methods of the character and Monster and just dont use a Surfaceview if i am right. We should serously think about it but i am not sure if it would be so easy because the movement how we thought it yet.

Comment: You will probably have to change some things to make it work, but really that's nothing compared to what you can do with LibGDX. In terms of speeds it will also increase the rendering time a lot and decrease the CPU usage, something very important when developing for Smartphones. And if later you want to add new features to your game, that will probably be all good. With Android and SurfaceView I think your are limited in terms of possibilities because of, again, rendering time on smartphones. Anyway good luck !

Comment: Thanks alot for the answers! But i guess we will develop it more or less like it is now. Lateron we can change the idea to LibGTX IF we are going improve the projekt more further. At this moment its just a Projekt and we are even happy that it works now.

To come back to one Question. Does onTouchEvent() is automaticaly multitouch so i can use it to notice more than one touch?